# Automating a page that uses jQuery drag and drop with Selemium Webdriver

Tags: jquery, ruby, selenium, automated-tests

It seems as if the css is not updating when I drag and drop something with Selenium.

```
    $driver.action.click_and_hold(item).move_by(0 , distanceToDrop).release.perform
```

The drag and the drop are working fine.  Its just like you are dragging it to a unsupported location and it springs back.  To my knowledge the page is using jQuery "sortables".  Below is the HTML for the section of the page that I am trying to automate.

```
    <p class="hint">Drop and drag the categories to the order they should appear on the screen.</p>

    <div class="sortables " id="yw0">
    <div class="sorted_items" id="4">Sample Inputs</div>
    <div class="sorted_items" id="3">Social Media Information</div>
    <div class="sorted_items" id="2">Numbers of Computers</div>
    <div class="sorted_items" id="1">Category 1</div>
    </div><form id="organize-categories-form" action="/listCustomFieldCategories/index" method="post">  <input type="hidden" id="new_order" name="new_order" value=""/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Selenium-WebDriver: 
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5149